# How to enable ipyparallel for Jupyter?

Tags: jupyter, ipython-parallel

There're docs scattered under Jupyter or ipyparallel, but there's no a single piece document illustrating the entire process from beginning to end. I am really confused. Can anyone has experience to share?

Here are checks about my environment.

```
$ipcluster --version
5.2.0

$which -a ipcluster
/home/etlolap/anaconda3/bin/ipcluster
/user/bin/cluster

$head -n 1 $(which ipcluster)
#!/home/etlolap/anaconda3/bin/python
```

I can see the Clusters tab in Jupyter but it still prompts to ask for installation of ipyparallel.
[image]

To enable the IPython Clusters tab in Jupyter Notebook:

```
ipcluster nbextension enable
```

But I got the following issue hence it didn't work. It looks that nbextension is even not a valid argument.

```
No subcommand specified. Must specify one of: ['start', 'stop', 'engines'].
```

Answer (score 12):

If you are using pip, this will get you the Jupyter notebook and IPython parallel:

```
pip install notebook ipyparallel
```

The package is fully functional at this point. You can start clusters with `ipcluster` and connect to them from notebooks. After installing ipyparallel, you can enable the IPython Clusters tab in the notebook dashboard:

```
ipcluster nbextension enable
```

If you are using [conda-forge](https://conda-forge.github.io), installing ipyparallel will automatically enable the extension:

```
conda install -c conda-forge notebook ipyparallel
```

If you are using conda but not the conda-forge packages (e.g. Anaconda), or you otherwise don't see the IPython Clusters tab, you can still run the command above to enable the extension:

```
ipcluster nbextension enable
```

Or disable it with:

```
ipcluster nbextension disable
```

Comment: I installed via Anaconda.

Comment: That falls under the "conda but not conda-forge" above, in which case `ipcluster nbextension enable` should do it.

Comment: What do you get for the ipyparallel version from `conda list`? It should be 5.2. You might want to do `conda install ipyparallel` to get a newer version.

Comment: The version of ipyparallel I can get from conda list is 5.2.0

Comment: then `ipcluster` is perhaps not the version conda expects. Try removing and reinstalling it, and perhaps also checking `which -a ipcluster` for problems in your PATH.